# collectionview binded inside tableview on device rotation

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uicollectionview

I have a collectionview inside a table view cell with a page control .

When the device gets rotated, the collection view cell doesn't take all width of the screen, instead, it shows 2 items, like :

[image]

I want for each picture to take all the space same as on portrait.

code : https://gist.github.com/alouanemed/831ec9e05929d669344e5f4000655d86

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try something like this.

```
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
    return CGSize(width: collectionView.frame.width, height: collectionView.frame.height)
}
```

**Edit:**  You have to confirm to `UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout` Delegate, to use this function.

Comment: I have that on my controller. forgot to add it to the snippet

Comment: mmmm you could check the device orientation and return the correct number of items displayed based on that, however this could also be constraints problem.

Comment: Itried using UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinator but it doesn't get called

Answer (score 0):

After adding @Tobi's code try to add `viewDidLayoutSubviews()`

```
override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
    super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()

    collectionView.setNeedsLayout()
    collectionView.layoutIfNeeded() 
}
```